# Repeat matrice title in other column in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

First I hope you're fine all of you.
Here what I have :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOsyI.png)
And here what I want to have :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTsOd.png)

The real list is dynamic and so long (more than 1500 usally) so I tried to do it cell by cell but the file take a lot of time (more than 15min) to manipulate the datas, I tried the array formula with this :
ARRAYFORMULA(IF(I2:I="";B2:B;IF(B1:B="";""; IF(I2:I;B1:B;A1:A)))) but it gives circular manipulation so an error.

If someone one can help me out I'll be thankful.

The real list is dynamic and so long (more than 1500 usally) so I tried to do it cell by cell but the file take a lot of time (more than 15min) to manipulate the datas, I tried the array formula with this :
ARRAYFORMULA(IF(I2:I="";B2:B;IF(B1:B="";""; IF(I2:I;B1:B;A1:A)))) but it gives circular manipulation so an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=scan(,B2:index(B:B,match(2,1/(B:B<>""))),lambda(a,c,if(istext(c)*istext(offset(c,1,))*isdate(offset(c,2,0)),c,a)))
```

[image]

Comment: it workd for the example but instead of Agent 1,2 ... there is names, so it doesn't work when I applied for the real sheet because the condition is to contain the value Agent.

Comment: updated the answer. Please test it out. It checks for two sequential text cells (Agent,Title) followed by timestamp cell.